# Devolver un valor de un DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como puedo obtener el valor de un **DropDownList** en el controlador, cuando selecciono una opción quiero llenar otro DropDownList con un script en cascada

En el Controlador lleno el **DropDownList** con el **ViewBag.Id_Empresa**

```
public JsonResult GetPasillos(int idEmpresa)
  {
    var listaBodegas = db.Tabla_Bodega.Where(b => b.id_empresa == idEmpresa);
    return Json(listaBodegas);
  }

public ActionResult Create()
  {
    ViewBag.Id_Empresa = new SelectList(db.Tabla_Empresa, "id_empresa", "nombre_empresa");
    ViewBag.Id_bodega = new SelectList(db.Tabla_Bodega, "Id_bodega", "Nombre_bodega");
    return View();
   }
```

Y en la Vista lo recibo así.
Luego con el script quiero realizar la Cascada

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("Id_Empresa", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
  </div>
}
@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#Id_Empresa").change(function () {
        $("#Id_bodega").empty();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '@Url.Action("GetPasillos")',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { empresaId: $("#Id_Empresa").val() },
          success: function (bodegas) {
            $.each(bodegas, function (i, bodega) {
              $("#Id_bodega").append('<option value="'
               + bodega.Id_bodega + '">'
               + bodega.Nombre_bodega + '</option>');
            });
          },
          error: function (ex) {
            alert('Falle en Recuperar las Bodegas.' + ex);
          }
        });
          return false;
      })
      });
  </script>
}
```

De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: edita tu pregunta colocando código en vez de imágenes. Así se hace más fácil reproducir tu escenario y motiva a responder. Saludos :D

Comment: Ok amigo escribí el código y elimine las fotos, gracias por tu consejo ya que esta es mi primera pregunta y no sabia como realizarla

Comment: no he hecho nunca con mvc, pero no tiene una propiedad onchange los dropdown? en ese caso puedes llamarla con una funcion y sacar asi el selected value para habilitar el otro combo y rellenarlo.

Comment: En el artículo que te indico a continuación, podrás ver cómo realizar un DropDownList  en cascada (Cascading DropDownList) en ASP.NET MVC. [Cómo crear un Cascading DropDownList en ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/11/24/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cascading-dropdownlist-en-aspnet-mvc)